# HAproxy, load balancing

Tags: apache, load-balancing, haproxy

I got three webservers, two run apache one is running haproxy for load balancing

Now I need to upload photos in my cms, how can I make sure that certain URL will go into certain server? , I mean one server needs to be a master and second just a slave 
Or there is another solution? 
Also if people is using a form such as contact-us how can i make user this databases are the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (replace with your values as needed):

```
frontend www-http
mode http
bind :80

acl app   hdr(Host) -i app.example.com
acl cms   path_beg  -i /cmspath

use_backend loadbalance if app 
use_backend cms if app01 cms

backend loadbalance
balance roundrobin
option httpclose
option forwardfor
server apache1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 check
server apache2 yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:80 check

backend cms
balance roundrobin
option httpclose
option forwardfor
server apache1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 check
```